# PJSUA2 / C++: Unable to find default video device (PJMEDIA_EVID_NODEFDEV)

Tags: c++, pjsua2

I try to excute the video demo application of pjproject "vidgui".
When I click on the button "Start Preview"

I receive this error message "Unable to find default video device (PJMEDIA_EVID_NODEFDEV)"

Can you help me please?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.